# Should URL change after form submission?

Tags: angular, express

I am serving Angular from `localhost:4200` and Express from `localhost:3000`. In my `localhost:4200/sign-up` route, I have a form with `<form action=https://localhost:3000/users/sign-up>`.

```
<form #form [formGroup]="userForm" method="POST" action="https://localhost:3000/users/sign-up">

 . . . 
 . . . 

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" (click)="form.submit()" [disabled]="!userForm.valid || !usernameIsUnique">
</form>
```

After I submit the form, I process the submission in Express, save the data (using `user.save()`) and just to test how things are working, complete the route by sending a response with `res.json(JSON.parse('{"foo": "bar"}')`.

```
exports.user_create_post = [
   . . . 
    (req,res,next) => {
        var user = new UserObj(
            { . . . });
        user.save(function(err) { . . . });
        res.json(JSON.parse('{"foo": "bar"}'));
 }]
```

After `res.json()` my URL remains at `https://localhost:3000/users/sign-up`, and I have a console error:
`Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://localhost:3000/favicon.ico (“default-src”).` (To keep things simple here, I'll try to address the `Content Security Policy` issue in a separate post).

Assuming there had been no errors, should the URL remain at `https://localhost:3000/users/sign-up` after the `res.json()` response, or should the browser URL revert to the `referrer`, i.e. `localhost:4200/sign-up`? In other words, in the normal case with no errors, does the form submission actually change the browser URL to the URL listed in the form `action` property ( `https://localhost:3000/users/sign-up`)? Or does it submit the data to the `action` property URL( `https://localhost:3000/users/sign-up`), but keeps the browser URL at the `referrer` URL (`localhost:4200/sign-up`)?

If indeed the form submission changes the URL to `https://localhost:3000/users/sign-up`, does that mean that `res.json()` is also sent to `https://localhost:3000/users/sign-up` (rather than `localhost:4200/sign-up`)? If so, this would explain why I'm having problems. Furthermore, assuming `res.json()` is sent to `https://localhost:3000/users/sign-up`, and not to the referrer (`localhost:4200/sign-up`), how can I re-direct to `localhost:4200/sign-up` AND send a JSON response to `localhost:4200/sign-up` (given that only one response is allowed per request)?

## Update

I made the excellent changes that @John Mgbako suggested, but now have a new problem, which is that my server tries to save the same document two-times per `POST` request (please see more details below). I now have:

Template:

```
<form #f="ngForm" [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="doSignUp(f)">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let key of keyArr; index as i"> 

    <label [hidden]='key[1]'> {{key[2]}}
      <div>
          <input *ngIf="key[1]==='password' type='password' [formControlName]='key[0]' id={{key[0]}} name={{key[0]}}/>
          <input *ngIf="key[1]!=='password' type='text' [formControlName]='key[0]' id={{key[0]}} name={{key[0]}}/>
      </div>
     </label>
    <br/>

    </ng-container>
    <button>Submit</button>

</form>
```

Component:

```
@Injectable()
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  data: Object;
  keys: string[];
  keyArr: any[] = [];
  formCtls: any = {};
  userForm: FormGroup;
  cookieValue: string;

  constructor(private member: MemberService, 
    private fb: FormBuilder, 
    private cs: CookieService, 
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    // IF COOKIE EXISTS THEN ALREADY SIGNED UP, SO REDIRECT . . .
    console.log("IN ON_CHANGES");
    const cookie = this.cs.get("SESSIONID"); 
    if (cookie) {
      console.log(`ID: ${JSON.stringify(cookie)}`);
      debugger;
      this.router.navigateByUrl('../two-fa',{relativeTo: this.route})
    } 
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.member.getSignupForm().subscribe((data)=>{
      this.data = data;
      this.keys = Object.keys(data["authData"]);
      this.keys.forEach((key,idx) => {
        let datArr = [];
          this.formCtls[key] = new FormControl('', {updateOn: 'blur'});
          if (key !== '_id') {
            datArr.push(key,
              data["authData"][key]["attr"]["hidden"],
              data["authData"][key]["attr"]["label"]);
          } else {
            datArr.push(key,true,'');
          }
        if (key === 'password' || key === 'hash') {
          let datArr = [];
          this.formCtls['password2'] = new FormControl('');
          datArr.push('password2', false, 'Password (again): ');
          this.keyArr.push(datArr);          
        }
      });
      this.userForm = new FormGroup(this.formCtls);
      if (this.data) this.got_data = true; 
      console.log("OnInit Data: " + this.data_string);
      this.cs.set('member-cookie','{login-name: ' + data["authData"]["username"]["value"].pop() + '}');
      this.cookieValue = this.cs.get('member-cookie');
      console.log ("Cookie: " + this.cookieValue);
      
      //Set up observable on the Username Input, to check if Unique
      this.formCtls['username'].valueChanges.pipe(
        filter((text: String) =>text.length > 2),
        tap(text=>console.log("Text 1: " + text)),
        debounceTime(10),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap((text: String) =>this.member.getUnique(text.toLowerCase()))
      ).subscribe(r=> {console.log(`Result from unique get(): ${r}`); 
            this.usernameIsUnique = (r > 0) ? false : true; // r is # of instances in DB
            console.log(`Unique? (length: ${r}): ${this.usernameIsUnique}`); });
    });
  }

  doSignUp(f: NgForm) {
    this.member.postSignupForm(f).subscribe((res)=>console.log(`RES: ${JSON.stringify(res)}`));
  }

}
```

Auth service (member service):

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MemberService {
  host_url: string = "https://localhost:3000/users/";
  signup_url: string = this.host_url+"sign-up";
  data: string = '';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getSignupForm(): Observable<any> {

    return this.http.get(this.signup_url,{responseType: 'json'})

  }

  postSignupForm(f: NgForm): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.signup_url, f.value);
  }

  getUserIdFromRoute(route: ActivatedRoute): Observable<string> {
    return route.paramMap.pipe(
      map((params: ParamMap) => params.get('id'))
    )
  }

  getUnique(s: String): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .get(`${this.host_url}unique?username=${s}`, {responseType: 'json'})
  }

}
```

Server route:

```
   . . . 
   . . . 
            user.save().then(()=> {
                res.cookie("SESSIONID", user.generateJWT(), {httpOnly:true, secure:true});

   . . . 
   . . .
```

The problems are now:

1. The server seems to be trying to save the same document 2x per post request (it saves correctly in MongoDB, then a little while later I get a server-side Dup Key error when the server tries to save the same Document again).
2. With no `BUTTON` element, nothing happens when hitting return in the input elements
3. With the `BUTTON` element, it's almost as if the form is submitted twice. Perhaps it's one requ4est when hitting `ENTER`/blurring out of the last `INPUT`, and one request when clicking on the `SUBMIT` button? (Incidentally, how does the form know the button is a `SUBMIT` button?).
4. My desired behavior is that the form will only submit when the `SUBMIT` button is clicked, not when the user enters `RETURN` in inputs.

How to fix this strange behavior in which the server tries to save the document twice per `POST` request?

### Solution

Adding `res.send('done') after` res.cookie()` solved the problem (i.e., back-end no longer tries to save the Document twice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you don't use the action attribute in form in angular, you can either use the form reactively or template e.g

```
<form #form [formGroup]="userForm" method="POST" action="https://localhost:3000/users/sign-up">
```

should be:

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```

add a onSubmit() function in component, this will handle validation and all your request call using angular `HttpClient`

Secondly Content Security Policy: has to do with the fact that your backend code does not have `CORS` or `CORS` was set to allow certain url. You can visit this link [Express CORS](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) on how to implement in your backend code. Your can also use Proxy configuration to handle the CORS on your angular project, visit this link [Proxy Config](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/configure-proxy-api-angular-cli/) on how to implement.

Comment: Many thanks for your excellent reply. I made the changes you suggested (amended to my original post), but am now having new problems whereby it seems the server is trying to save the same document two-times per `POST`` request. Many thanks in advance if you have some further ideas on how to solve that!

Comment: Can you explain more, i am trying to understand the problem you are facing

Comment: thank you for your reply. Please note that thanks largely to your great suggestions, the problem is now solved. Please see my "Update" at the end of my Original Post above. I needed to add `res.send("done")` after the `res.cookie()` response. Doing so got rid of all the strange behavior with double-saving of Documents in MongoDB, CORS problems, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few aspects to this question.

1. Why would you use `form`'s `action` attribute to submit the `form` when you can use Angular's `HttpClient`? That way you'll have more control on where to redirect the user after you get a successful response from your Express API.
2. The user should ideally be navigated to some sort of a landing page. This can either be a dashboard page, a main application landing page where the user is supposed to land after sign-up/login or this can also be a page where you show them a message saying that an email has been sent to their registered email address with a confirmation link or something of that sort.
3. Considering that you mentioned `/sign-up` route, it would be safe to assume that you've also implemented routing. So you can very well, inject the [**`Router`**](https://angular.io/api/router/Router) as a dependency and call [**`navigate`**](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate) on it in order to navigate the user after successful response.
4. Finally, you might probably get a CORS error since your Angular App and your Express App are running on separate PORTs. So the browser will block CORS on it. You can use the [**`cors`**](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) middleware in order to deal with it.